# BeagleBone Green Wireless(BBGW) can not boot form eMMC

Tags: beagleboneblack

BeagleBone Green Wireless(BBGW) was booted from SD card successfully.
After that, I removed the SD card by my hand.

Reboot the system, then I can not login through SSH.

I observe the 4 LEDs. It seems the system booted from eMMC normally. Heartbeat LED works well.

Questions:

1 Why can't the BeagleBone Green Wireless(BBGW) boot from eMMC again？

2 Is there a method to recover the board to factory state？

Answer (score 0):

reason found:

edit the file in eMMC: /etc/fstab

delete the line I added some days ago:

/dev/mmcblk0p1  /mnt   vfat defaults  0  0

/dev/mmcblk0p1 is actually the eMMC device, I thought it was the SD card.

reboot.It works well.